# Deleting from a detailed view in React Native / Redux with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm building a React Native app using Redux and React Navigation. I cannot figure out how to delete an item from it's own view. It has a very simple layout:

- Level 1: Index - A list of all the items.
- Level 2: Detailed view - Passed the id of the item in detail, then grabs the proper data from map state to props.

In the detailed view I need to include a "delete" button, but when I update the state (immutably - of course) it is still looking at the detail view and throws a lot of errors because the array element with the data is no longer in the state at all.

**My Index.js render**

```
render () {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <List>
      {
        this.props.inbox.map((el) => {
          return (
            <ListItem
              key={el.ownerId}
              title={el.owner}
              onPress={ () => navigate('MessageView', { ownerId: el.ownerId, ownerName: el.owner }) }
            />
          )
       })
     }
 ...
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    inbox: state.inboxReducer.inbox
  }
}
```

**Detail View**

```
  _deleteMessage () {
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
    this.props.deleteMessage(this.props.queued_msg._id)
  }
...
render(){
   <Button
      backgroundColor='#E81E63'
      title="Login"
      onPress={this._deleteMessage.bind(this)}
      buttonStyle={styles.button}
      title='Delete Message' />
}
```

What my state array looks like:

```
queue: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      owner: 'John Lennon',
      owner_id: 1,
      walker: 'Sally Sue',
      scheduled_for: new Date(),
      walker_id: 1,
      message: 'Rex peed and pooped.',
      logged_at: new Date()
    }
...]
```

Comment: Your provide code seems not relevant... `queue`, `queued_msg` only happened at one place. how does `queued_msg` pass in?